# Avoid using object to hold int, bool, double application setting values

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I have some code to handle integer, double, Boolean, and string settings. Right now, each setting variant extends an abstract class, where the setting value is stored as an `object`.

Is there any way to avoid this? What I'd like to do is have `IntSetting` objects return their `Value` as an integer, `DoubleSetting` objects return their `Value` as a double and so on and so forth.

Here is the code referenced above:

```
public abstract class ModelSetting
{
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public abstract string ToString();

    public ModelSetting(object value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class IntSetting : ModelSetting
{
    public IntSetting(int value) 
        : base(value)
    {
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return (bool)Value ? "1" : "0";
    }
}

public class DoubleSetting : ModelSetting
{
    public DoubleSetting(double value)
        : base(value)
    {
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ((double)Value).ToString("%g");
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be pseudo code `IntSetting => (bool)Value ? "1" : "0";` and would be off topic here.

Comment: @Heslacher I think it's real code with a glaring bug

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you say, returning an `object` isn't ideal. This is a relatively straightforward use case for generics:

```
public abstract class ModelSetting<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public abstract string ToString();

    public ModelSetting(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

Then implementing classes can use:

```
public class DoubleSetting : ModelSetting<double>
{
    //...The rest of the class
}
```

---

This:

```
public abstract string ToString();
```

Is bad. `ToString` is already defined on `Object`, so by declaring an abstract version here, you're not overriding, you're [*hiding*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). This is far less frequently done, and for good reason- it breaks our basic expectations of polymorphism. You should only do it with good reason, and you don't have one here. Just get rid of the `ToString` redeclaration, it gives you nothing.

---

You require a `value` in your constructor, but then let `Value` be set publicly. This doesn't really make much sense- somebody could just pass default(T) to the constructor, making the constructor meaningless. You're giving two different ways to set the value, for no particular reason. It's not a big deal, but is needlessly confusing.

Consider whether you actually need to be able to change `Value` for an existing `ModelSetting` instance. If so, remove the constructor. If not (and this is probably better!), make the property `private set`. This makes the value *immutable*, which makes it much easier to reason about the class. For example, if I hold an instance, I know I can pass that instance to whoever I want without having to worry about them changing the value without me expecting it.

---

```
return (bool)Value ? "1" : "0";
```

Shouldn't this be the `BoolSetting` version, rather than the `IntSetting` one? At least you can take comfort that this bug is a demonstration of one of the advantages of the strong-typedness that you get from the generic approach!

Comment: One more question before I accept your answer. How should I store the settings in a collection? What I'd like is a mapping of string values to `ModelSetting` objects (i.e. a `Dictionary<string, ModelSetting>`). Is this possible?

Comment: I decided to use a `Dictionary<string, object>` and hide the casting details with methods like `public void AddSetting<T>(string key, ModelSetting<T> value)`. Thanks again!

Comment: You could also define a non-generic interface `IModelSetting` that `ModelSetting<T>` extends. Then your Dictionary is a little more strongly typed (you know you can only have `IModelSetting`s). Alternatively, you could use an abstract class. I've done both in similar situations.